# How to insert one column into other column within the same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to insert one column's data into another column within the same table.

Can anybody tell me how to write this?

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET col_2 = col_1
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to copy data from one column to another on the same table:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
    destination_column_name=orig_column_name
WHERE condition_if_necessary
```

IF you want to add a new column and copy the original data to that column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   ADD new_column_name column_type NULL

UPDATE table_name SET
    destination_column_name=orig_column_name
WHERE condition_if_necessary
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the column to be non-nullable, then you can set it to a default value before doing the update.

```
begin transaction
alter table Song add SortArtist nvarchar(128) not null default N''
go
update Song set SortArtist = Artist
commit transaction
```

Answer (score -2):

alter table [dbo].[GetPermission]
 add username1 varchar(100) ----------------ading new column username1

update GetPermission   set username1=*username*