# update data column with data from another column plus an additional keyword

Tags: sql, db2

I have tried using a combination of both of these two previous questions [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541916/how-to-insert-one-column-into-other-column-within-the-same-table-in-sql-server) [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822694/create-mysql-column-with-string-variable-from-another-column-plus-additional-in) to help me with my issue.

My issue is I am trying to set one column in DB2 equal to another column with a beginning and ending value.  I do have the option of doing this in two steps, of adding the S- first and then on a second pass add the -000 on the end, but I am currently running into the issue of CONCAT not working in DB2 like in MYSQL.

Pre-conversion

```
name  |   loc      |  group
-----------------------------------
sam   |   123      |   
jack  |   456      |   
jill  |   987      |   
mark  |   456      |   
allen |   123      |   
john  |   789      |   
tom   |   123      |
```

Post-conversion

```
name  |   loc      |  group
-----------------------------------
sam   |   123      |   S-123-000
jack  |   456      |   S-456-000
jill  |   987      |   S-987-000
mark  |   456      |   S-456-000
allen |   123      |   S-123-000
john  |   789      |   S-789-000
tom   |   123      |   S-123-000
```

The SQL I am trying to use:

```
UPDATE table 
SET GROUP = CONCAT('S-',LOC,'-000') 
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(LOC)) = 3
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB2 CONCAT takes only two arguments, so you could nest them to achieve your desired result.

```
UPDATE table 
SET GROUP = CONCAT(CONCAT('S-',LOC),'-000') 
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(LOC)) = 3
```

Comment: I had tried and just retried that and I am receiving: If "<value>" is a literal string in the SQL statement, it is too 
long for its intended use.

Comment: @em3ricasforsale What are the data types of the `loc` and `group` columns?

Comment: Nice call.  They are two different sizes, but that ultimately would have been the issue even if they were the same size was.  The issue was that they had extra spaces and with the new values on each side it was now greater than the column size.  Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a concatenate operator: ||

However some recommend not to use it

```
UPDATE table 
SET GROUP = 'S-'||LOC||'-000'
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(LOC)) = 3
```

If you're LOC field is longer than 3 and you want no whitespace

```
UPDATE table 
SET GROUP = 'S-'||RTRIM(LOC)||'-000'
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(LOC)) = 3
```

Comment: Recommendations against the use of the double-bars is likely mostly due to the `|` character being *variant* in EBCDIC; in that case, there is the `CONCAT` operator as an equivalent\synonym for the `||` operator.  For example, the expression `'S-'||RTRIM(LOC)||'-000'` might be written instead, as `'S-' CONCAT RTRIM(LOC) CONCAT '-000'`, to eliminate use of variant characters in any operator.